# Al intentar instalar un plugin en wordpress tengo ahora la pantalla en blanco

Tags: wordpress

hoy he instalado un nuevo wordpress ya que no he sido capaz de recuperar la instalación anterior. al instalar un plugin me dice que wordpress no tiene permisos, por lo que en el config.php he añadido las directivas del ftp. pero luego he cambiado a otra opción del panel de administración y ahora tengo la pantalla en blanco ni puedo logearme.

¿Que puedo hacer?

lo he solucionado dando permisos a la carpeta wp-content y añadiendo define('FS_METHOD', 'direct'); al config.php

Answer (score 0):

Si dice que no tiene permisos un plugin. Deberías de entrar a tu server y darle permisos a esa carpeta que el plugin te indicaba. 
Si ahora no podes loguearte ve los cambios que hiciste y revertí, caso contrario volve a instalar de nuevo.